# IE7 negative position issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jvvmU/2/

Render it in Firefox and IE7.. In Firefox, it works fine, but in IE, a long scrollbar shows.

How to fix this bug?

**Note:** I've also this problem in Android based browsers, in landscape mode.

Comment: hi @kikio direction tag not support ie7 ......... check to support tag http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the incompatibility in IE7 here is that the width of the html document is smaller than the width of the element labelled `id="e"`. In the fiddle that you've provided the view port is about 660px wide, if the element `e` is 660px or less, then the green box appears as in other browsers.

What are you trying to achieve here? Are you sure that css is the best way to achieve your goal?